# AngularJS Cross Origin Request using http GET Blocked

Tags: angularjs, cors, http-get

I need to access ***http://www.wienerlinien.at/ogd_routing/XML_TRIP_REQUEST2?locationServerActive=1&type_origin=any&name_origin=60201095&type_destination=any&name_destination=60200769***
(returns an XML file)

->This causes a cross origin request Error (unfortunately service is only available via http).

I also enabled cross-origin in my server. Howevery without any success.

```html
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync({
        notify: true,
        port: 8000,
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist",
            middleware: function (req, res, next) {
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                next();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the function which performs the http request:

```html
  this.requestjourney = function (id1, id2) {
        
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            timeout: 5000000,
            // url: "http://www.wienerlinien.at/ogd_routing/XML_TRIP_REQUEST2?locationServerActive=1&outputFormat=JSON&type_origin=any&name_origin=Reumannplatz&type_destination=any&name_destination=Stephansplatz", 
            url: "http://www.wienerlinien.at/ogd_routing/XML_TRIP_REQUEST2?locationServerActive=1&type_origin=any&name_origin=" + id1 + "&type_destination=any&name_destination=" + id2,             
            locationServerActive: 1,
            excludedMeans: 0,
            excludedMeans: 1,
            excludedMeans: 3,
            excludedMeans: 4,
            excludedMeans: 5,
            excludedMeans: 6,
            excludedMeans: 7,
            excludedMeans: 8,
            excludedMeans: 9,
            excludedMeans: 10,
            excludedMeans: 11,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

Is there any kind of cook book solution fixing cross oringin request in angularJS? Or Workaround ?

Thanks in advance,
Wolfgang

Comment: My only experience is related to Web Api 2 when attempting to enable CORS on the server side. Here's a helpful link (assuming that Web Api is applicable in your case) - http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html .

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that CORS is enabled on server side?
When I request the URL from my web page, I don't get an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header back. (And Firefox complains about the missing header in the developer console.) This header is the minimum requirement for things to work.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

And in case of doubt, try with jQuery instead of Angular first, e.g. with $.get(url).

Comment: I tried jQuery, unfortunately this does not solve the problem.             XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.wienerlinien.at/ogd_routing/XML_TRIP_REQUEST2?locationServerActi…in=any&name_origin=60201095&type_destination=any&name_destination=60200769. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.